# IBooks on iPad: 2-page view for PDF

Tags: ipad, pdf, books

for my studies I am very frequently using iBooks on my iPad, and for many PDF files it would be great to have them displayed, such that 2 pages are shown next to each other.
It is a very common thing for me to have to skip back and forth,  so that this would really help.

I have allready seen a few questions akin to this one, however none exactly delivering what i need.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem and after some research, I figured out that apparently this feature only implemented in iBooks for ebooks and not for pdfs (also still in iOS11). Hence, I switched to the foxit reader app, which is very convenient to handle.